# node.js jade - how do I set the content type in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a view in which the MIME type returned varies.  How do I set the content type in the head section?

Here is what I am trying to do

```
!!!
html
  head
    title #{site.title} - #{site.version}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js')
    content-type #{mimetype}
  body!= body
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify the [content-type meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) like so:

```
meta(http-equiv="content-type", content="#{contentType}; charset=UTF-8")
```

Remember that the tag for content-type is `<META ...`

Comment: The OP is asking about mime content-type, not SEO keywords.

Comment: @broofa read the question again. He was asking how to set the tag ... yes, I grabbed the wrong specific section, I was just using the first example at my hands.

Comment: Guess I completely misunderstood what he meant by, "How do I set the content type" ;)

Comment: @broofa to be perfectly fair, my very FIRST thought on reading the question was "goto the controller, set it on the header" but then I saw where he was trying to inline it as via the example given ;)